# How to fix "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list" error when attempting to crawl information from website?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi there I am trying to crawl some information from a recruitment website in China and I am encountering some problems at the very last lines of my code. The error is of the type "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list". Please see the last paragraph for more details.

I have already tried searching questions that match my error code but to no avail.

```
# Define parameters and headers 

def get_one_page(city, keyword,page):
'''
Obtain content of HTML
'''
paras = {
    "jl": city,
    "kw": keyword, 
    "kt":3,
    "p":page,
}


headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 
Safari/537.36',
'Origin': 'sou.zhaopin.com',
'Referer': 'https://www.zhaopin.com/',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
'DNT': 1
}
url = 'https://sou.zhaopin.com/?' + urlencode(paras)

# Attempt to connect to website

try:

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    return None
except RequestException as e:
    return None
# Crawling begins

def parse_one_page(html):


pattern = re.compile( ... )


items = re.findall(pattern, html)   

for item in items:

    yield {
        'Source Link': item[0],
        'Job': item[1],
        'Company': item[2],
        'Salary': item[3],
        'Type': item[4],
        'No. of people' : item[5]
    }

# Output of results to csv file

import csv
def write_csv_headers(path,headers,rows):
 with open(path, 'a', encoding='gb18030', newline='') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()
    f_csv.writerows(rows)

def write_csv_headers(path, headers):

with open(path, 'a', encoding='gb18030', newline='') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writeheader()

def write_csv_rows(path, headers, rows):

with open(path, 'a', encoding='gb18030', newline='') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
    f_csv.writerows(rows)

def main(city,keyword,page):

filename =['zl_' + city + '_' + keyword + '.csv']
headers = ['Source Link', 'Job', 'Company', 'Salary','Type','No. of 
people']
write_csv_headers(filename, headers)
for i in tqdm(range(page)):
    '''
    Obtaining info from website
    '''
    jobs = []
    html = get_one_page(city, keyword,i)
    items = parse_one_page(html)
    for item in items:
        jobs.append(item)
    write_csv_rows(filename, headers, jobs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main('Beijing','Software Testing', 10)
```

The error code is as follows, many thanks in advance!

---

> > TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
> >         last)
> >          in ()
> >          35 
> >          36 if **name** == '**main**':
> >         ---> 37     main('Beijing','Software Testing', 10)
> >          38 
> >          39
> >
> > in main(city, keyword, page)
> >          22     filename =['zl_' + city + '_' + keyword + '.csv']
> >          23     headers = ['Source Link', 'Job', 'Company', 'Salary','Type','No. 
> >         of people']
> >          ---> 24     write_csv_headers(filename, headers)
> >          25     for i in tqdm(range(page)):
> >          26         '''
> >
> > in write_csv_headers(path, headers)
> >           8 def write_csv_headers(path, headers):
> >           9 
> >         ---> 10     with open(path, 'a', encoding='gb18030', newline='') as f:
> >          11         f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers)
> >          12         f_csv.writeheader()
> >
> > TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: `filename = 'zl_' + city + '_' + keyword + '.csv'`

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on what you are trying to drive at, thank you.

Comment: Change `filename =['zl_' + city + '_' + keyword + '.csv']` to `filename = 'zl_' + city + '_' + keyword + '.csv'`

Comment: @Rakesh Thank you for your help. In fact I am really new to programming and I was just trying to tweak the code provided in a tutorial. After doing what you said, I received this error  get_one_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page' , which I believe has something to do with my last line of code main('Beijing','Software Testing', 10) and html = get_one_page(city, keyword,i). Is it possible for you to look through it again, your help is really appreciated!